# Dynamically create and assign id to an input?

Tags: javascript, html

My code is below but I'm unable to verify if it's correct, or if it is, why I can't access the created text inputs by id

```
for (i=0;i<t;i++)
{
div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML+"<input id="+i+"\" type='text' value="+(i+1)+">"+"<br>";
div1.innerHTML=div1.innerHTML+"<input id=a"+i+"\" type='text' value=a"+(i+1)+">"+"<br>";
gont.innerHTML=gont.innerHTML+i;
}
```

Comment: In your first <input> it looks like the ID will be a number. ID's have to start with a letter. Also, it seems that you are adding a quote after the ID (\") but not not one before it. I would use id=\"a"+i+"\"

Comment: @Jez D ID's don't have to start with a letter. it just has to be unique.

Comment: @user3428295 , how are you accessing the inputs?

Comment: I'm using more javascript, another button which activates another function stored on the same file, it's meant to cycle through the ids, collecting each of the inputs and printing them. This is what I worked out so far:    

var h=document.getElementById("questions").value;
var r=parseInt(h);
var div2=document.getElementById("haha").value;
for (j=0;j<r;j++)
{
var k=j+1;
var u1=document.getElementById(k).value;
div2.innerHTML=div2.innerHTML+u1;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = 2;

var div = document.getElementById('idDiv');

for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<input id=" + i + "\" type='text' value=" + (i + 1) + ">" + "<br>";
    div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + "<input id=a" + i + "\" type='text' value=a" + (i + 1) + ">" + "<br>";
    gont.innerHTML = gont.innerHTML + i;
}
```